# Is it possible to create a smart mailbox in Mail.app mixing "any" and "all"

Tags: macos, apple-mail

For example, a smart mailbox which filters (from OR to a certain email address) AND in the inbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've since discovered that there is a better way. By using the "Spotlight" features you can create a single smart mailbox that filters both Mailbox and sender. Simply use the "from:" syntax with "OR", but note that you need to choose "Entire Message" not "Sender" for this syntax to work:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to create two *Smart Mailboxes*. One that matches *any* of a selection of email addresses, and the other matching *all* of the conditions:

- In mailbox *Inbox*
- In mailbox *"the other Smart Mailbox"*

[image]
[image]